# Php - middleware

Tags: java, php, middleware

I am developing a php based application which has java as middleware for web services. Is there any frameowork/middleware available in  php stack which allows me to write services in php and also hosted on php based app server, lets say Zend?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically I'd expect the middleware to be the webservices - are you consuming or providing webservices using PHP?

Not that it makes much difference, PHP supports both.

You can roll your own solution, or use [PHP Soap](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php), the [nuSoap PHP lib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) and [xmlrpc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlrpc.php). There's also the [php/java bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/how_it_works.php) which implements a socket based abstraction for both ends (but obviously this is not strictly a web service).